# Travel with more than one passport

Tags: passports, asia

I'm planing a trip between many countries in Asia. I'm not sure if it is safe carry two passports of different countries. Of course both are valid and legal.

I'm scared to travel in poor countries with a high level of corruption and have a problem with stupid things.

If a have to choose between a Brazilian or a Portuguese which one is better?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regarding the question if it is good or bad to travel with two passports, this is a duplicate as noted in the comments above. Regarding if the Brazilian or Portuguese is better, you should check the visa requirements of the different countries you travel to first.

On a general note I would think that a Portuguese passport is better than a Brazilian one since Europeans are considered to be in Asia rather for business than for low-salaries job-seeking than Brazilians. (Japan for example has a quite high number of Brazilian immigrants working in poorly paid jobs in factories etc). So a Brazilian passport might cause more question on a border than a Portuguese one.

Comment: (+1) Wikipedia provides lists for [Brazilian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Brazilian_citizens) and [Portuguese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Portuguese_citizens) citizens. Assuming they are correct and up-to-date, the main difference in Asia is indeed Japan and South Korea, the rest is a wash and Russia even seems to be easier for Brazilians.